# Best algorithm to fill pages with collages

Tags: ruby

I'm working on an algorithm to fill a book with a number of pictures.
Each has a single picture of an collage of 8, 10 or 12 pictures.
There is a constraint on the maximum pages in the book. 
I need an efficient algorithm to get layout the pages so that:

1. All pictures are used
2. The number of pages is as close to the maximum as possible

I could resolve this with a little recursion but I recently read something about Dynamic Programming and figured this might be a good problem for DP.
Having absolutely zero experience with DP I did some research but I didn't find a good example/tutorial that describes a problem like this.

Could someone give me a explanation about how and where to start?

Comment: Do you need to always fill each page with exact number of photos? If so, are there a constraints on numbers of input photos - for example must be even number, at least 30 photos, and no more than 12 * max_pages?

Comment: No each page could be 1, 8, 10 or 12. There's no min value for number of photos. If it is less then the number of pages, the number of pages will be the number of photos. The input value is indeed 12*max_pages